# App crash when asking Permission when using RecyclerView in fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, crash, user-permissions

I was showing all the songs in recyclerView and for this i need the user-permission. Now i have implemented the code for user-permission in the main Activity and recyclerView is in a fragment. So when app ask for user-permission then only the user-permission dialog box is visible but app doesn't open.

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestStoragePermission();
        }else if(this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //getSongArray();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerId);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new ZoomOutPageTransform());

    }

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 100;
    private void requestStoragePermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // file-related task you need to do.
                }
                else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

RecyclerViewFragment

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerView songListRecycleView;
    recyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<songInfo> songs;

    public void RecyclerViewFragment(){

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment_layout,container,false);

        /**setting recycler view**/
        songListRecycleView = view.findViewById(R.id.songListViewId);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        songListRecycleView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // setting ArrayList
        songs = new ArrayList<>();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("okay_till_now","yes");

        mAdapter = new recyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),getSongArray());
        songListRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }


    public ArrayList<songInfo> getSongArray(){
        ArrayList<songInfo> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
        songInfo sInfo;

        Cursor c = getSongCursor();
        int songPathIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int songTitleIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        //Toast.makeText(, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        sInfo = new songInfo("Hello Mayank","no path to this");
        songsList.add(sInfo);
        songsList.add(sInfo);
        Log.v("Cursor_length",""+c.getCount());
        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
            //sInfo = new songInfo(c.getString(songTitleIndex),c.getString(songPathIndex));
            //songsList.add(sInfo);
        }
        return songsList;
    }

    public Cursor getSongCursor(){
        try{
            Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = new String[]{
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                    //MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            };
            String selection = null;
            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE+" ASC";
            Cursor songCursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(externalUri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder);
            return songCursor;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

errors

```
2019-06-22 11:44:05.909 14962-14962/com.example.mymusicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mymusicplayer, PID: 14962
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mymusicplayer.RecyclerViewFragment.getSongArray(RecyclerViewFragment.java:78)
        at com.example.mymusicplayer.RecyclerViewFragment.onViewCreated(RecyclerViewFragment.java:60)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6606)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6606)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6606)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6606)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6606)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6606)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:727)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22105)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2467)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6886)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:841)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:772)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1015)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
2019-06-22 11:44:05.909 14962-14962/com.example.mymusicplayer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: doesn't open mean crashed?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: What is line 78?

Comment: int songPathIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA); this is at line 78.

Comment: I want to know that as I am asking permission in the mainActivity and then recyclerView is a fragment and in that fragment i am using this permission. So even if app starts will the recycleView will be visible when mainActivity asked the permission.

Comment: Before loading your recyclerView check if permission is granted or not. If you already have permission then load your recyclerView else ask for permission from fragment itself, after the callback of the permission result decide whether to show your view or proper message to the user.